# How should one calculate variance from RGB values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

What can the way of finding variance of RGB values that are stored in a text file.

[image: Text File]

**I tried this:**

```
filename = 'test.txt';

fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');

M = textscan(fid, '%d %d %d');

M = cat(2, M{:});

fclose(fid);
```

The above code reads all the RGB values from text file but is not able to find out variance through var(M).

Answer (score 0):

convert M into double.
try:

```
M_d = double(M);
varArr = var(M_d);
```

Comment: glad to help :)
if the problem is 100% solved and you don't have any more comments- please accept the answer (by marking the V sign)

Comment: I did click on it but I guess I don't have enough points to do it. But I clicked to accept you as best answer.

Comment: are you sure? it seems that it didn't capture your mark.
anyway, the important thing is that your problem is solved - good luck :)

Comment: @Leo [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)